# How do I use the elements in a list as an arg?

Tags: python

I want to take an input of an infinite amount of numbers so I can add, subtract, multiply, and divide all the numbers together.

I'm converting all the numbers given into a list so I can separate them from one another. But I can't really figure out how to access the numbers from inside the list.

[image: This is a screenshot of the prompt, It will probably give more useful information]

[image: This is a screenshot of what the code is giving out]

```
given_numbers = list(
    input("Please give me two or more numbers: ")
)  # Gets the numbers that are going to be used
given_operator = input("What do I do with these numbers?: ")  # Gets the operation

number_list = []  # The list the numbers given are going to be inside of
# numbers_ready = number_list # Just a placeholder for when I figure this out

for n in given_numbers:  # Removes spaces and commas
    if n.strip() and n.replace(",", ""):
        number_list.append(n)

def calculator(*num, **operator):
    
    if "add" in operator.values():
        lst = list(num)
        result = lst[0]

    for n in lst[1:]:
        result += n

    print("Result: ", result)

if "subtract" in operator.values():
    lst = list(num)
    result = lst[0]

    for n in lst[1:]:
        result -= n

    print("Result: ", result)

if "multiply" in operator.values():
    lst = list(num)
    result = lst[0]

    for n in lst[1:]:
        result *= n

    print("Result: ", result)

if "divide" in operator.values():
    lst = list(num)
    result = lst[0]

    for n in lst[1:]:
        result //= n

    print("Result: ", result)
```

Comment: `list(input("prompt"))` is not how you turn the input into a list. It will make each character a separate list element. Use `split()` to split at whitespace.

Comment: Text should be provided **as text**, not as screenshots.

Comment: ...and beyond that, code should follow [mre] rules, being only the shortest code that reproduces a narrow, specific error on which your question is focused. See also [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122)

Comment: please fix your indentation

Comment: ...which is to say: If your real question is about putting numbers into a list or passing that list as a series of arguments, there's no reason for you to give us your assignment specification or code that isn't specifically related to list management; doing so distracts from the question rather than clarifying it.

Answer (score 0):

```py
given_numbers = list(
    input("Please give me two or more numbers: ")
)
```

Doing this you are splitting each characters that you type. For example:

`>>> Please give me two or more numbers: 1 2 3 4`

Will be a list like that:

`['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3', ' ', '4']`

Instead, use this line of code:

```
given_numbers = input("Please give me two or more numbers: ").split(" ")
```

It means that you take a string as an input, after that you split this string in a list separating when there is a space.